# multiplication of these two functions is bit difficult to me! can anyone explain what is going on in this!

Tags: probability

This is a question to obtain f(x,y) from f(y|x) and f(x). simple multiplication would do but I am confused how to multiply these functions which are dependent on each other in a curious manner! 
where 'f' is probability density

[image: Refer to This image for function graph!!]

Thanks

Comment: $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_{Y|X}(y|x)$. So you should plug in $\alpha=x$ and go ahead and multiply. You'll get zero when $y$ is not between $x/20$ and $x/10$; what happens otherwise?

Comment: actually it was intermediate ,after that I had to find f(y) , when I multiplied I got:
f(x,y) =1/5x for x in [0,200] and y in [x/20,/x/10] 
which on integration does not yield :
f(y)=y/100 for y in [0,10] and 1/5 -y/100 in (10,20]

Comment: You should actually have $f_X(x)=\frac{x}{20000}$ for $x$ between $0$ and $200$.

Comment: got It . Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You know that for a given value of $X = x$, $Y$ can only be between $\frac{x}{20}$ and $\frac{x}{10}$.

If you plot this on a 2-D graph, you get the possible x,y pairs. Note that Y is bounded by the lines y = x/20 and y = x/10. (following image from Wolfram Alpha)

[image: (y > x/20) AND y < x/10 AND x > 0 AND x < 200]

But you want $f(x,y)$, which is $f(y | x) \times f(x)$. Note from the graph that this is non zero only if $y$ is between $\frac{x}{20}$ and $\frac{x}{10}$, and if x is between 0 and 200. And if y is in that range, it's:

$f(y|x)\times f(x) = f(x,y) = \frac{20}{x} \times \frac{x}{20,000} = \frac{1}{1000}$, if $0 \leq x \leq 200$ and $\frac{x}{20} \leq y \leq \frac{x}{10}$

Turns out this distribution is a function of the specific values of x and y at all, and is a uniform distribution for the given ranges of x & y !

As a sanity check, you can see that the area of the triangle in the graph multiplied by the "height" of the distribution (1/1000, it would be sticking out of the page) should be 1, because it's a probability distribution of 2 variables and it's volume (i.e. surface area times height) should be 1.